# Pass field value as variable in vue axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have the below code in that I want to pass the array key as a variable I tried it but it uses variable not its value. Here is my code.

```
var fieldName = 'firstName'
axios.post('/user', {
    fieldName: 'Fred',
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

In request actually, the value of post array key is **fieldName** it should be **firstName**

Actual POST request array

```
{"fieldName":"John"}
```

Expected POST request array

```
{"firstName":"John"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the key  in square brackets.

```js
{ [fieldName]: fieldValue, }
```